# It's time to reopen this question

Tags: discussion

[Does "Where ever there is more than one of you gathered in My name" apply to the Internet?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/does-where-ever-there-is-more-than-one-of-you-gathered-in-my-name-apply-to-the)

This question is perfect for this site. It's very relevant, and we need a canonical answer.

Comment: I would think this could be reworked (and reasked - way to old to migrate) as a question for the [Biblical hermeneutics SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8):

> closed as primarily opinion-based by fredsbend, El'endia Starman♦ Jul 1 '14 at 22:44

Do you disagree with this? I’d say that it’s very clearly an opinion-based question (or, as we call them here, a “Truth” question). If you disagree, please give clear reasons.